# Neon animation end of animation event?

Tags: javascript, polymer, css-animations, web-component

I have built a small web applications with polymer and I use neon animations.
I want to measure fps in automated tests of specific animations (e.g. hero-animation and ripple-animation).
Is there a animationEnd event in neon-animation, or how do I determine the end of the animation?

Comment: There’s an [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event in general.

Comment: I have tried that one. But it doesn't fire for paper-material. I will add a jsfiddle later

Comment: You can add a listener for `neon-animation-finish` which then calls a function. Check out #23 of the Polycasts series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) which has some great info on how to use neon-animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `neon-animation-runner-behavior`, when the animation is complete, the event `neon-animation-finish` is fired. You can add a *listener* for this in your element which will call a function when the event is fired. For instance:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-animated-element",
    behaviors: [
      Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
    ],
    properties: {
      animationConfig: {
        value: function () {
          // config here
        }
      }
    },
    listeners: {
      'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
    },
    _onNeonAnimationFinish: function () {
      alert("animation finished!");
    }
  });
</script>
```

More info on how to use the `neon-animation` elements can be found in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) awesome video.

Comment: Works. In a neon-animated page the event gets fired on the neon-animated-pages element.